# Getting rid of "Attending?" in Android calendar event, using the Calendar API

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm creating a local calendar on an Android device, and inserting events into this.
Here is my code (using dummy data for now):

```
public static Uri createCalendarWithName(Context ctx, String calendarName, String displayName, Account account) {

    Uri target = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.toString());
    target = target.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type).build();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    values.put(Calendars.NAME, calendarName);
    values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, CALENDAR_COLOR);
    values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    values.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, account.name);
    values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    values.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, "Europe/Oslo");
    //values.put(Calendars.ALLOWED_ATTENDEE_TYPES, "0");

    Uri newCalendar = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(target, values);

    return newCalendar;
}

public void addEventToCalendar(){

    long calID = getLocalCalID();
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;     
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2013, Calendar.MAY, 5, 14, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2013, Calendar.MAY, 5, 14, 55);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "Siste frist for å ettersende papirer");
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Hei!\n\n");
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Oslo");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    Log.i("EventID", ""+eventID);

    cr = getContentResolver();
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Reminders.MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(2, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    values.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
    values.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    uri = cr.insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

The calendar and event are created as intended, but opening the event reveals a row named "Attending", with three radio buttons: "Yes, Maybe and No".

Are there any way of getting rid of this row/radio buttons? This choice will anyhow not have an effect what so ever in an event in a local calendar, I presume...

I'm using an Android 4.0.4 device btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding both these lines seem to solve the problem:

```
values.put(Events.ORGANIZER, calendarOwner);
values.put(Events.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA, 1);
```

Not quite sure why!

Ref: https://gist.github.com/mlc/5188579

Comment: what do you mean by not quite sure! answer only those question,whom you sure about that.

Comment: values.put(Events.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA, 1); solved the problem! :D